# How to get the UIButton ID?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have created 5 buttons dynamically in Swift like this:

```
for theIndex in 0..<5 {

        let aButton = UIButton()
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width / 2 - 120, self.view.bounds.height / 2 - 150, 240, 300)
        aButton.setTitle("Button \(theIndex)", forState: .Normal)
        aButton.addTarget(self, action: "btnClicked:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(aButton) 
    }
```

But how can I get the **BUTTON_ID** for each one?

```
 func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject?) {
        let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc_name") as! DetailVC
        vc.selectedId = **WANT_TO_PASS_BUTTON_ID_HERE**
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
```

Comment: consider setting the `tag` of the buttons *OR* store an array of your 5 custom buttons in your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tag` property of your buttons (for example, you can set there a button's index), and retrieve it later in `func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject?)` method to determine a button with which index was pushed

While cycling through your indexes do:

```
aButton.tag = theIndex
```

and in `btnClicked` method do:

```
vc.selectedId = sender.tag
```

See for reference [Apple docs on UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag)

Comment: I am new to iOS. Could you please show me the use of tag for buttons?